# "JBoss Web/2.1.7" logs location

Tags: jboss, logging

When I get an exception displayed from my Spring MVC app deployed to JBoss, there is a note at the bottom saying "The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/2.1.7 logs."

Where can I find these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JBoss's `log` directory, e.g. under `server/default/log`

Comment: That is what I was expecting, but the only log file being created there is the server.log, and the full stack trace is not in there.

Comment: Actually,  I tell a lie, the stack trace in the server.log is more complete than the one displayed on the web page. Despite still not containing the info I was hoping for, I think that is obviously what the note is referring to!